# FolderBrowserDialog not showing up on second form

Tags: c#, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

Ok, this is the main essence of what I am trying to achieve and the symptoms of what it is doing.

I have a main windows form. On this form the user can click on a button that will open up a new and seperate form. This form will have a button that is supposed to display a FolderBrowserDialog. Instead it simply locks up form2 and never displays anything.

Here is essentially the code I have dealing with the form etc.

This is in the first form that is loaded after i do some uninteresting things.

```
FORM1.cs
//do stuff
//In a button.click method I do the following
Application.Run(new Form2(myParameters1, 2, 3));
```

This is the second form that is called from the first form

```
FORM2.cs
//do more stuff with the parameters on load
//user clicks on a button
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;
    fbd.Description = "This is the browser dialog box";

    if(fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

After I click on the button the dialog box does not show up and the form2 gets locked from doing anything.

I have also attempted changing the

```
fbd.ShowDialog()
```

To

```
fbd.ShowDialog(Form2.ActiveForm)
```

with the same results.

Any help would be appreciated! If you need more info let me know and I can try to provide all that I can.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention (and actually completely forgot) That the method that opens up the second form is a seperate thread.

So the first form starts a thread, which opens the second form, which is supposed to open a dialog which it is not. Now i think it has to do with the threading..

Comment: I copied all your code and it worked fine for me, besides the syntax error at Desktop() <----

Comment: Why are you calling Application.Run(new Form2(myParameters...) instead of something like var newForm = Form2(...); newForm.Show();

Comment: @KDiTraglia oops.. sorry about the syntax error. ><

Comment: Why you use this line: `Application.Run(new Form2(myParameters1, 2, 3)); `. Do you have already launched the first form with Application.Run?

Comment: @TimLentine hmm.. not really sure.. I will try that and see what happens. Maybe that is the problem, and I'm not sure why it worked fine for KDi.. >< i was thinking it was something simple and stupid i was forgetting etc.

Comment: Actually on further investigation it only worked if I call it from the constructor of Form1, if I put it elsewhere it throws exceptions, so that is probably your issue

Comment: I attempted the running it as a newForm.ShowDialog() and same result.. And yes i am opening the second form from a button click, i guess i didnt mention that, i will edit it to clarify.

Comment: I forgot that my first form starts a thread which opens the second form... >< its been a while since i have looked at that part of the code exactly. lol

Comment: @BrandonStout You should put your 'SOLVED' response as an answer to your question rather than answer in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out my issue. It ended up being that the thread from Form1 that was opening Form2 was not able to open DialogBoxes because it was seperate from the UI thread entirely.

I ended up working around using that thread and just eliminated it completely which solved my problem. The dialog box opened up just as I wanted.

Thank you all for the responses though! They did help me figure out a few other things I failed to do correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. Main GUI thread was creating a backgroundworker thread to write to database but when background thread is failed used to show a custom control dialog to save exception file. THis custom dialog was shown correctly however Browse button on it to open folderBrowserDialog to save the exception file wouldn't show. My custom control would show "Not Responding" in its title bar.

What I did was instead of calling Custom Control directly I made it call on UI thread itself 
like this.

```cs
void DBThread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {                
            this.Invoke(new CrossThreadExceptionHandler(CatchInterThreadException), e.Error);                
        }
    }
```